# How do I get jgit to find a different head if master isn't there?

Tags: java, jgit

I'm using this code to create a powerpoint with changed files:

```
try (Git git = new Git(repo)) {

            DiffFormatter df = new DiffFormatter(NullOutputStream.INSTANCE);
            df.setRepository( git.getRepository() );

            Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();
            for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
                if(commit.getParents().length != 0) {
                    System.out.println("LogCommit: " + commit);

                    List<DiffEntry> entries = df.scan(commit.getId(), commit.getParent(0).getId());
                    for( DiffEntry entry : entries ) {
                        String filename = entry.getPath(DiffEntry.Side.NEW);

                        if(!filename.equals("/dev/null")) {
                            Integer currentCount = 0;

                            if(fileChanges.containsKey(filename)) {
                                currentCount = fileChanges.get(filename);
                            }else {
                                System.out.println("    DiffEntry: " +entry.getPath(DiffEntry.Side.NEW));
                            }
                            fileChanges.put(filename, new Integer(currentCount + 1));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However when I run it on a repo:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.NoHeadException: No HEAD exists and no explicit starting revision was specified

                at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LogCommand.call(LogCommand.java:154)

                at .GitAccessor.getFilesChanged(GitAccessor.java:47)

                at Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

I've tried to replicate it (since it is on a client's machine) by making this repo without a master: 
https://github.com/davidahines/no_master

I've tried deleting the HEAD, ORIG_HEAD, and FETCH_HEAD and still can't seem to get this error.

I think what I need to do is bypass this check somehow, or find another head within the refs folder but I can't find that within jgit.

I don't currently have access to the client's repo because it is closed source.

Comment: I haven't seen a `NoHeadException` while computing diffs. Are you sure the exception stacktrace originates from the diff code? In your post, the centred code line seems to belong to the stacktrace, but there's no `LogCommand` used in your code snippet. I've seen the `CreateBranchCommand` raising this exception.

Comment: It originates from this line: Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call(); 

I added the full exception above.

Comment: JGit 'thinks' that no start point was given and tries to resolve `HEAD`. It seems that your client's repository has no ref at all. Otherwise `all()` would set the `startSpecified` flag to true.

Comment: Hmm, do you know what could cause that? I believe they don't work in master they work in branches like 2.02, 3.03.

Comment: Well, if there were branches, the exception shouldn't occur. Did you try to run the code on an empty repository, i.e. created with `Git.init()` and `HEAD` deleted?

Comment: Nope, I haven't but I did create a repo without master and the code seems to run fine with that.

Comment: The code fails if. there are no branches at all and no HEAD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that jgit doesn't support the tilde shortcut for /home/username, once that was removed it worked.